# Собрать инфу о переходе по ссылке

Tags: python, django, url, fingerprint

Делаю проект на django.Надо собрать информацию о переходе по ссылке - подробный фингерпринтинг:таймстемп,браузер,адрес,например.Какие технологии надо использовать,ведь обычный обьект request на такую инфу беден:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И так... IP:

```
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip
```

<sub>(***[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581789/)***)</sub>

Browser:

```
request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

Как таймстэмп не знаю...